# locked of screen lock - time password app

Tags: lock-screens

My son has downloaded a screen lock app on his phone which changes the password every minute according to the time. However a few day in, the app has stopped working and he is now unable to get access to his phone. We have no clue how to fix this problem and would appreciate idea.
this is the link to the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adriadevs.screenlock.ios.keypad.timepassword

Answer (score 3):

**Being that this is a third party app, you can put your phone into safe mode, and uninstall the app**.

Being that, when you boot your phone into Safe mode, it doesn’t run any third-party apps installed on your device. therefore, your lock screen will not appear in safe mode.

To go into safe mode on a Samsung (I don't know what phone you have) do the following:

1. Turn your phone off.
2. Then, Press and hold the Power  button, until you see the animated  Samsung logo appear.
3. Release the Power button, and press and hold the Volume down button.
   Keep holding it until your device boots up.
4. You can let go when you see the words "Safe mode" in bottom-left corner.

(It should be similar on most phones, but if it's not the same on yours, then search Google for "how to enter safe mode on [name of your phone]")

When in safe mode, go to settings -> apps -> time password (or whatever the app is called on your phone) -> uninstall.

If the uninstall bottom is greyed out, go to settings -> security -> device administrators, and turn off the app from being an admin.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I now have a happy son who can use his phone.

Comment: @PernilleWoodhead i would also suggest you don't use third party lock screens as you have seen for yourself how easy it is to bypass