# Password has appeared but i've not installed it!

Tags: lock-screens, password

My partner uses her Lenovo tablet all the time , she doesn't use any password or pin just a swipe after boot up screen BUT tonight she booted up its got to the " desktop" screen but when she swipes it comes up asking for  PASSWORD , we've tried all known passwords yet it just says " WRONG PASSWORD " after 5 attempts it shuts down , there's no " Forgotten password " choice!

I'm at a loss , we don't really want to do a reset as she will lose pics that haven't been backup!
It's a Lenovo yoga tablet 2

Comment: Is it maybe a Sim password? If you have a Sim card in it, remove it and see if that helps

Comment: There's no sim in it !

Comment: Oh well, just a guess. The only thing i can think of is that someone thought it was funny to set up a password while she wasn't looking.

Comment: I'm the only one been near it so it can't be that , she loaded 2 games yesterday that she saw in an advert thing not the store so i wonder if its a bug! We do think the house is haunted !!

Comment: If you suspect an app is responsible for this, try following instructions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187725/241679) let me know how it goes

Comment: Got it to say safe mode bottom left but as soon as you swipe it still comes up Password !

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas. Let's see if anyone else has an answer as to how a password set itself up without human intervention.

Comment: I'm baffled & i don't do baffled!! Cheers anyway

Comment: Could you go to [Google Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/find) and Lock your phone? It should ideally now ask you to use your Google email and password to unlock. Make sure you are connected to the internet.

Comment: Its a tablet , can't get any further than turning it on wait for home screen & that's it , when its normally swipe to continue it now asks for a password! which we didn't set up!!

Comment: @Paul harpratap is saying that you should go online to the link provided, and lock the device. On older devices you can set a custom code that will be asked of you when signing in. So go to Google device manger from a different device, and after logging into the same Google account as the tablet, press on lock device, put in a password and lock. Then go to your tablet and put in the same password